# How to add custom xml attribute to xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

While designing a GUI in C#, in the xaml file, I created a shape like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Data" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartRectangleStyle}">
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Data_DragThumb" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Data}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
</Style>

<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data}" ToolTip="Data" StrokeThickness="2">
    <s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource Data_DragThumb}" x:Name="MyShape"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </s:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate>
 </Rectangle>
```

And this GUI works fine so far, enabling me to save the shape in a xml file. For saving the output as xml, the serialization part of the code is like this:

```
XElement serializedItems = new XElement("ConfigurationItems",
    from item in designerItems
    let contentXaml = XamlWriter.Save(((DesignerItem)item).Content)                                       
    select new XElement("ConfigurationItem",
        new XElement("X", Canvas.GetLeft(item)),
        new XElement("Y", Canvas.GetTop(item)),
        new XElement("Width", item.Width),
        new XElement("Height", item.Height),
        new XElement("ID", item.ID),
        new XElement("zIndex", Canvas.GetZIndex(item)),
        new XElement("ParentID", item.ParentID),
        new XElement("Content", contentXaml)
        )                                             
);
```

The output xml file is this:

```
<Root>
  <ConfigurationItems>
    <ConfigurationItem>
      <X>256</X>
      <Y>190.54</Y>
      <Width>130</Width>
      <Height>117</Height>
      <ID>fef14b95-4abb-44ea-a298-26d6e16a765e</ID>
      <zIndex>0</zIndex>
      <ParentID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ParentID>
      <Content>&lt;Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" ToolTip="Data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner;assembly=GUI"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;Rectangle Name="MyShape"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;300&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;200&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt;&lt;/ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;/dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt;</Content>
    </ConfigurationItem>
  </ConfigurationItems>
  <Connections />
</Root>
```

Now I want to do two things:

**The first goal**, I want to add the `x:Name` property value as an `XAttribute` to the `XElement`, so that the saved xml file should look like this:

```
<Root>
  <ConfigurationItems>
    <ConfigurationItem Name="MyShape">
      <X>256</X>
      <Y>190.54</Y>
... ...
```

For this purpose, I tried to add the following line in my code for serializing items:

```
XElement serializedItems = new XElement("ConfigurationItems",
    from item in designerItems
    let contentXaml = XamlWriter.Save(((DesignerItem)item).Content)                                       
        select new XElement("ConfigurationItem",
        new XAttribute(" Name", item.Name.ToString()),
    ... ...
```

But this gives a totally blank value for the 'Name' attribute in the output xml file like this:

```
<Root>
  <ConfigurationItems>
    <ConfigurationItem Name="">
      <X>256</X>
      <Y>190.54</Y>
... ...
```

**The second goal**, I want to let the user be able to change the `Name` tag value in my GUI. For instance, what I want is, by default the `Name` tag should be equal to the `x:Name` property of the shape defined in my xaml file. But when the user right clicks on the shape and select an item, maybe called 'add new name', a textbox appears and the user enters a name like 'Rocket', creates another same shape on the canvas and name it as "Aircraft", then I want the xml output file should look like:

```
<Root>
  <ConfigurationItems>
    <ConfigurationItem Name="Rocket">
      <X>256</X>
      <Y>190.54</Y>
... ... 
    </ConfigurationItem>

    <ConfigurationItem Name="Aircraft">
... ...
```

Could someone help me on solving these two problems? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's using either Dependency property or Attached property (try some reading at msdn). Btw, I only looking at your title and only skimmed through the post.

Comment: Are you sure that `item.Name.ToString()` is not empty?

Comment: It is empty, that is the problem.

Comment: could you post a working sample which have the issue, may I have a look. difficult to identify the actual issue.

Comment: I don't know how to post a sample. Do you mean a working 'exe' of my GUI or the whole code?